# How to delete a consecutive duplicate row in C matrix?

Tags: c, matrix

I want to delete a consecutive row in a matrix. For example:
My matrix has 3 rows and 3 columns.
Elements of the matrix would be:
1 2 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
For this example the output should be:
1 2 3
4 5 6

I've tried an implementation but I have some problem, I know that I must use another matrix whose rows must be modified but I don't have any correct results till now.

How can I make it work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void readMatrix(int matrix[100][100], int noRows, int noCol);
void removeLine(int matrix[100][100], int noRows, int noCol);
void printMatrix(int matrix[100][100], int noRows, int noCol);

int main()
{
    int noRows, noCol, matrix[100][100], i, j;

    printf("n="); scanf("%d", &noRows);
    printf("m="); scanf("%d", &noCol);

    readMatrix(matrix, noRows, noCol);
    printMatrix(matrix, noRows, noCol);

    return 0;
}

void removeLine(int matrix[100][100], int noRows, int noCol)
{
    int i, j;
    int temp[100][100];
    for (i = 0; i < noRows - 1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < noCol; j++)
        {
            if (matrix[i][j] == temp[i + 1][j])
            {
                matrix[i][j] == temp[i + 1][j];

            }
        }
}

void readMatrix(int matrix[100][100], int noRows, int noCol)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < noRows; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < noCol; j++)
        {
            printf("\na[%d][%d]=", i, j); scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
}

void printMatrix(int matrix[100][100], int noRows, int noCol)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < noRows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < noCol; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Description doesn't say what the problem is.

Comment: You can't remove rows from an array. You can copy all rows after the one to remove left one position.

Comment: This looks like C++ but you have tagged it C. Please fix.

Comment: @MYousefi i edited it, but  i think that it's obvious that the problem is that i can't make it work

Comment: Check this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540980/how-to-delete-a-row-from-a-2d-array-in-c

Comment: @JohnnyMopp sorry for that, i edited it now and it s C, my mistake was that i still used the .cpp extension instead of .c when i created the file.

Comment: in function: `removeLine()`  this statement: `matrix[i][j] == temp[i + 1][j];`  is a comparison due to the `==`  *untitled1.c:34:30: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]* perhaps you meant: `matrix[i][j] = temp[i + 1][j];`  note: `=` (an assignment) rather than `==`.  If your compiler did not warn you of this problem, then either enable the warnings or get a better compiler

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*   2) the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 100.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: regarding this function signature:  `void removeLine(int matrix[100][100], int noRows, int noCol)`   Much better to place the `noRows` and `noCol` before `int matrix[100][100]` such that the parameters can be used in the declaration of the `matrix[][]`.  Suggest: `void removeLine(  int noRows, int noCol, int matrix[ noRows ][ noCol ] )`   This kind of pattern needs to be followed whereever the `matrix[][]` is defined.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);`  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: the `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful 'input format conversion specifiers` (or EOF).  Suggest:  if( scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for matrix entry failed\n" );`  probably followed by `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: this statement: `int noRows, noCol, matrix[100][100], i, j;` is not a good idea,  Suggest: `int noRows;  int noCol;`  Then input the values for those two variables, then on a new line: `int matrix[ noRows ][ noCol ];`  Which will use the `variable length array` feature of C to declare the `matrix`

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `for (i = 0; i < noRows - 1; i++)`  It is always a good programming practice to limit the scope of a variable as much as possible.  Suggest: `for ( int i = 0; i < noRows - 1; i++)`  which will limit the scope of `i` to the body of the `for()` loop

Comment: The function: `removeLine()` is not actually called anywhere in the posted code.  perhaps you meant it to be called in `main()`, immediately after the call to `readMatrix()`

Comment: in function: `removeLine()` the matrix `temp[][]` is never initialized so using that matrix as a source for a comparison is undefined behavior.

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to omit braces '{' and '}' around a multi statement body of a `for` code block.

Comment: strongly suggest using 'dynamic memory allocation' in the `removeLine()` function and passing back the pointer to the dynamic memory when returning from the function.  (be sure to pass the dynamic memory allocation to `free()` before exiting the program.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove rows from the 2d array. You can shift rows to the left:

```
// Helper function to "delete" one row from the array
void deleteRow(int matrix[100][100], int row, int noRows, int noCol)
{
    // Copy all rows after row to one row over
    for (int i = row; i < noRows - 1; i++) {
        // Use memcpy to copy entire row
        memcpy(matrix[i], matrix[i+1], sizeof(int) * noCol);
    }
}

// Remove repeats
void removeLines(int matrix[100][100], int *noRows, int noCol)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < *noRows - 1; i++) {
        // Use memcmp to compare entire row
        if (memcmp(matrix[i], matrix[i + 1], sizeof(int) * noCol) == 0) {
             deleteRow(matrix, i+1, *noRows, noCol);
             i -= 1;
             *noRows -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

There is room for optimization here - especially when there are more than 1 repeats.

Comment: I ve run in an exception when i tried to run the code."Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
noRows was 0x3."

Comment: @Leobej Note that I changed the value to be a pointer. You could also leave it a int and have the function return the new number of rows.

Comment: This answer will leave a duplicate row of the last row and the one before it.

Comment: @user3629249 Yes, as I mentioned in the answer you can't delete a row, only overwrite. But the function modifies the `noRows` variable based on the number of rows "removed".